# Is landscape-common still developed/maintained? Alternatives?

Tags: landscape, system-info

landscape-common wasn't included in Ubuntu Server 15.10, and depends on python2, not python3 which will be the new default in 16.04 LTS. Is it still developed/maintained or should I look for alternatives, and if so, which?

I use landscape-common to query my server for a general status message remotely (not only as an MOTD).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if landscape-common will ever be ported to python3, it depends on twisted. That being said, you should be able to install it manually even if it's not in the default image. It will pull in python2 dependencies but should work.

Comment: Thanks! I can confirm that it does work just fine, I was just hoping not to depend on deprecated packages.